# binary operator "<<" can't be applied to the expressions of type "wostream" and "string"

Tags: c++, string, stream, clion

I'm having this message printed as an error

> binary operator "<<" can't be applied to the expressions of type "wostream" and "string".

by CLion's inspector ( my IDE) , whenever my code looks like this.

```
 stringstream ss;
            ss << "Foo baré féé bar"
               << someObj->aStdStringProperty << endl;
```

(accents like "é" on purpose )

It compiles and links just fine and it's really the string member part that makes it throw an error.

*FYI, I'm not the one who has written this, it's on a project I'm working on.*

I'm no used to strings, wostreams, w_char and all that stuff in C++, so I'm a bit confused about whether it's my IDE being too harsh or myself misunderstanding my lessons/readings.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think you need to use `std::wstring` when using the wide char streams. I'm not that familiar with them myself, but a quick test on ideone.com shows that it worked when I changed `std::string` to `std::wstring`.

Comment: If it compiles and links fine, your IDE is wrong. As it is, you can see that you are *not* using a wide `stringstream`. (Or, your question doesn't match the real code, in which case we have no hope of helping you).

Comment: I believe the problem is that `anStdStringProperty` is a `std::string` but his colleague is using a wide-char stream. In the submitter's code he's using `std::stringstream` so of course that would compile fine.

Comment: Silly me, "foo bar" is not that accurate of the situation, because it does use some accentuated letters ( french ) I'll update ASAP the question.

Comment: But as my test with just "foo bar" yield the same thing... It's really the string part that is causing the "error"

Comment: @KurtStutsman thanks ideone is definitely helpful :)

Comment: @Drenghel I don't think the code is equivalent still. Your literal string there is still a normal `char` string even though you've embedded non-ASCII bytes. To get a `wchar` string literal you need to do `L"Foo baré féé bar"`.

Comment: @KurtStutsman I just wanted to be more precise about it. In case it would have been relevant. But duly noted !
About equivalence of the actual code, and the one shown. I really can't find anything else to copy. The literal actual used is a simple french sentence for debug purpose.
Only thing I could add is saying that stringstream are used all over the code 
`stringstream ss; ss << "----------" << endl;`  without an issue.

Comment: @Drenghel According to the error your colleague is using a wide-char iostream like `std::wstringstream` which isn't compatible with `std::string`. I don't know how he's managing to do that, but if you changed your code to use `wstringstream` you'd probably get the same error.

Comment: I noticed this problem today too (and I'm not using any accented characters or anything--plain sub-127 ASCII). CLion thinks I have an error but my compiler works and my program runs fine.

Comment: If `ss` is a `std::stringstream` and `myLiteral` is a `const char *`, it appears that CLion thinks the output type of the expression `ss << myLiteral` is `ostream<wchar_t>`, not `ostream<char>` (as I would expect). Knowing this explains why CLion thinks there is an error. Is there some reason for thinking that CLion is correct about `ostream<wchar_t>`?

Comment: @brian_o, glad I'm not the only one :). I was worrying I was creating my own problems ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was indeed a bug of CLion that has been fixed recently :)

[Bug Report Page](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-8300)

[Clion CLion 2016.3.4](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2017/03/clion-2017-1-eap-nested-namespaces/)

Thanks for the thought anyway :)